# D3 How to pass text value from data to variable

Tags: d3.js

I got a great answer yesterday helping me set up a conditional rule that allows me to display the points on my scatter chart as images or dots based on a variable  `'displaytype'`

Here's the link to the answer:  [D3 conditionally append image OR circle element based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849641/d3-conditionally-append-image-or-circle-element-based-on-variable/65850169#65850169)

I'm porting my solution into Power BI and the dataset will contain a field 'display_type'  which will be either 'image' or 'dot'

So I'm trying to update my variable and link it to the data but the if statement doesn't seem to recognise the output from the function.

eg

The Current variable is:

`var displaytype = "image"  // or "dot"`

I'm trying to change that to:

```
var displaytype = function(d) {
  return d.display_type
};
```

or

```
var displaytype = function(d) {
  return data[0].display_type
};
```

However, the result has no impact to the display whatsoever so I guess I'm missing something (probably simple) ?

Any help much appreciated as always

Comment: Can you post a link to the dataset? Is displaytype the same for all rows or does it vary ?

Comment: If it does not vary you could use var displaytype = data[0].display_type;

Comment: var displaytype = data[0].display_type works.   I had originally declared the variable before the dataset but by moving down after the data, it now works.  Thanks